# Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, oop

I know there were a lot of questions related to this, but I couldn't find information that would help... I just need to solve this problem in my script, does anyone could help me with that?

```
function dateValidation() {

this.validateDate = function() {
    var twoDates = {
        inputDate: $('#employmentDate').val(),
        todaysDate: new Date()
    }
    return twoDates.inputDate.getTime() < twoDates.todaysDate.getTime();
}
}
var validation = new dateValidation();
validation.validateDate();
```

This error I'm getting on the line 8:

```
return twoDates.inputDate.getTime() < twoDates.todaysDate.getTime();
```

Thank you

Comment: share value of `$('#employmentDate').val()` ?

Comment: `inputDate: $('#employmentDate').val(),` This is not an object of the type `Date()` so unless you convert it to a date you will not be able to call getTime() on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `Date` object instead string, Change this line

```
inputDate: $('#employmentDate').val(),
```

To

```
inputDate: new Date($('#employmentDate').val()),
```